# Firefox CSS Animation Not Working

Tags: css

How come this is not working in firefox?

```
<div>
    <i></i><i></i>
</div>
```

[image]

Jsfiddle.net/Calou/5juNw

Comment: Please provide a link to the fiddle rather than a screenshot. That is exceptionally unhelpful.

Comment: Because you used only the `-webkit-` vendor prefix. An approach that isn’t future-proof at all. You have to include _at least_ the code without the prefix and if you’re going to include vendor prefixes, include them all.

Comment: comment your animation css code

Comment: take a look at this:
@-webkit-keyframes barrelRoll {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes  barrelRoll {
    0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, When source code contains //@ sourceMap comments this error is produced in the console:

```
SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate sourceURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
```

But this is not an error,This breaks parts of the fidelity.com Web site. The Mutual Fund screener at fidelity.com doesn't work in Firefox 25 and the Web console shows this error.

according to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=926595 this is bug of mozila browser.